# Add UIScrollView with Paging to Existing UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I'm wanting to add a UIScrollView with paging to go through different views from my existing view controller which is the root view of my app.  I also have tab bar and navigation bar controllers along with it. Can I add a scroll view to this view controller to accomplish what I'm wanting, and if so, can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about it?

Here is my view controller.

```
#import "KFBViewController.h"
#import "ListViewController.h"
#import "ActionAlertsViewController.h"
#import "MarketUpdatesViewController.h"
#import "AgStoriesViewController.h"
#import "KFBNewsViewController.h"
#import "MemberBenefits.h"
#import "SocialNetworks.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "YouTubeView.h"
#import "KFBFlickrViewController.h"
#import "RSFM.h"
#import "UAPush.h"
#import "TUSafariActivity.h"

@interface KFBViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation KFBViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Home", @"Home");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home"];
        self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) showMenu
{
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kentucky-farm-bureau/id580530986?mt=8"];
    NSArray *activityItems = @[urlToShare];
    // TUSafariActivity *activity = [[TUSafariActivity alloc] init];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)gotoSecondView
{
    YouTubeView *youTubeView = [[YouTubeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"YouTubeView" bundle:nil];
    youTubeView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:youTubeView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)gotoPublicAffairs
{
    ListViewController *publicAffairs = [[ListViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
    [publicAffairs setWebViewController:wvc];
    publicAffairs.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:publicAffairs animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)gotoActionAlerts
{
    ActionAlertsViewController *actionAlerts = [[ActionAlertsViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
    [actionAlerts setWebViewController:wvc];
    actionAlerts.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:actionAlerts animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)gotoMarketUpdates
{
    MarketUpdatesViewController *marketUpdates = [[MarketUpdatesViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
    [marketUpdates setWebViewController:wvc];
    marketUpdates.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:marketUpdates animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)gotoAgStories
{
    AgStoriesViewController *agStories = [[AgStoriesViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
    [agStories setWebViewController:wvc];
    agStories.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:agStories animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)gotoKFBNews
{
    KFBNewsViewController *kfbNews = [[KFBNewsViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
    [kfbNews setWebViewController:wvc];
    kfbNews.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:kfbNews animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)gotoMemberBenefits
{
    MemberBenefits *memberBenefits = [[MemberBenefits alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    memberBenefits.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:memberBenefits animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)gotoPhotos:(id)sender
{
    KFBFlickrViewController *photosView = [[KFBFlickrViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBFlickrViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photosView animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)gotoSocialNetworks
{
    SocialNetworks *socialNetworks = [[SocialNetworks alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    socialNetworks.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:socialNetworks animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)gotoFarmMarkets
{
    RSFM *rsfm = [[RSFM alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    rsfm.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rsfm animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [UAPush openApnsSettings:self animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = @"Home";

    UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"\u2699" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(settingsButtonPressed:)];
    [settingsButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsButton;

    UIBarButtonItem *systemAction = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = systemAction;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 10):

This works really well for me:

Declare a property for your `UIScrollView`, and set your ViewController as a `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *theScrollView;

@end
```

**Note that I'm setting up my `UIScrollView` with code, but it can easily be done with a XIB.

In `viewDidLoad:` of your ViewController

```
    self.theScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 300)];
    self.theScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.theScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.theScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;     
    self.theScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.theScrollView];

    NSArray *viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects://your UIViews];

    for(int i=0; i<viewArray.count; i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.theScrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.theScrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [subview addSubview:[viewArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.theScrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.theScrollView.frame.size.width * viewArray.count, self.theScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Most paging scrollViews also have a `UIPageControl` associated with it. To do that, override this `UIScrollViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.theScrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.theScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.thePageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: It crashes on this line: [subview addSubview:[viewArray objectAtIndex:i]];

with unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc18acd0

Comment: Which line? @user2029585

Comment: Did you load the `viewArray` with your `UIView` objects? It seems like it's crashing because your `viewArray` is empty, or full of nil objects.

Comment: KFBViewController *home = [[KFBViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"KFBViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    HomeTwo *homeTwo = [[HomeTwo alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeTwo" bundle:nil];
    
    NSArray *viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:home, homeTwo, nil];

Comment: Are you loading the `viewArray` with `UIView` objects? Or `UIViewController` objects? Because 'home' seems to be a viewController.

Comment: They are both view controllers.

Comment: A `UIViewController` can't be added as a subview on another `UIViewController`. That's probably why you're getting the crash. You should be adding UIViews.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I'm wanting without getting rid of my current view controllers and creating UIViews in their place?

Comment: You could use a ContainerView to embed one ViewController inside another, but I don't know if that would play nice with a paging UIScrollView.

Comment: I will probably just end up doing swipe gestures to show two different controllers.  The only problem I have with this is figuring out how to do a back animation when swiping right to go back to the first view controller.  I can get the animation for the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

This link helps for you. Here page controller and scrollview both are used -

[PageControl Example in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps try using [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html), rather than a regular paging scrollview.

Apple's [PhotoScroller sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) provides a very good example of how to use `UIPageViewController`.

I also have some [code on github](https://github.com/stephsharp/PhotoScroller) that modifies PhotoScroller to load the `UIPageViewController` inside a `UIViewController` subclass. (In Apple's sample code, the `UIPageViewController` is the root view controller.)

I have never used a `UIPageViewController` with different `UIViewController` subclasses in each page (the PhotoScroller sample code uses `PhotoViewController`s in all pages), but I can't see why it couldn't be done with a few modifications to the code.